# QGIS 3 keep creating a "palettes" useless folder

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Fresh installations of QGIS 3.0.x systematically create a "palettes" folder in c:/ on Windows. Even if you delete it, it gets recreated after every restart/reinstall of QGIS.

Any trick to get rid of this folder once and for good? Or at least to change the path in which it is created?

Comment: So it does... Interesting.

Comment: I have not experienced this same issue, and I manage QGIS installations on about two dozen Windows machines. Is your installation from the standalone installer or OSGEO4W?

Comment: I suggest you submit a bug report.

Comment: This happened to me also. I was just installing 3.0.3 version.

Comment: Also creates a pallettes folder on server drives as well.

Comment: I don't have such a folder on Windows 10.

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone I have on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was reported the issue as a bug and it was fixed in QGIS 3.2 before.  [Bug report #19534](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19534)

Answer (score 3):

Best action would be to file a bug report at:

https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues/

Once you have an account use the "New Issue" tab.